# Find out Requires WP tag for a plugin when submitting it

Tags: plugin-development

I am going to submit my first plugin to the repository. How do I find out the Requires tag value for which my plugin would work? I know its somewhat vague, but how do you guys figure out? Like my plugin just add some info in the head section. The only thing required for its functionality is `wp_head` hook. So I just did a grep and checked the inline documentation that it was introduced in WP v1.2

So am I right? This is how I should be doing it? Any tips?

Comment: [Automatically determine minimum WordPress version required for a plugin?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/49817/3898) is a related thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yepp, if you really only use that hook, that would be the way to go. But it's pretty likely you also use a couple of WP functions...if so, you should check these functions, too, before going too low with your required version.

Generally, i wouldn't go below 2.0 (which i smore than 5 years old) for any new plugin. I think even going lower than 2.5, which is about 3 years old, is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! It really doesn't use anything other than `wp_head` hook. Its here - http://wp.me/pah88-ek